# Can Deno bundle TypeScript into JavaScript for Browser?

Tags: deno

I tried to bundle TypeScript with Deno, but it seems like it doesn't have the browser types.

I would like to use Deno as a simple option instead of WebPack etc.

```
console.log(window.document)
```

```
deno bundle browser/play.ts
```

Error

```
error: TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'document' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.
console.log(window.document)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following `tsconfig.json` option needed to be added to Deno (and also added to VSCode deno config).

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "deno.ns"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the compiler options I use to target the browser:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "dom.iterable",
            "dom.asynciterable",
            "deno.ns"
        ]
    },
}
```